# how to update rendered variable in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2, backend

I'm trying to render a variable that will update multiple time in the code, but it just renders the last one to the template,
for example on :

**views.py:**

```
def test(request):
    message = 'first massage'
    #do something
    message = 'second massage'

    return render(request,'test.html',{'message':message})
```

**test.html** :

```
<h1> {{message}} </h1>
```

It only displays the second message, but I want it to display the first message then after it changed, display the second message. Any help ?

Comment: Look at your view function, you render your template once with the last state of your `message` variable. You can change the variable as long as you want, but the template will be rendered with the last state only.
Notice, Django renders a static HTML document. If you want to make a dynamic page, you should use AJAX or SPA. Or the easier way is using the javascript which uses the passed values and show them one by one.

Comment: You can use different variable names for both the messages. Then finally send both the variables to the template.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to change your 'message' variable dynamically ( like 'message' variable has something to do with your models),

   a.)Update your 'message' variable using python in views.py,
   Create an api which returns JsonResponse.Then you can fetch this data through
   JavaScript and update (document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML=``${message}`)

   **in Views.py**

   ```
   def testapi(request):
      # do something
      return JsonResponse({"message":"VALUE_OF_MESSAGE"},status=201)
   ```

   **in javascript file**

   ```
   fetch('/testapi')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp); //output=> {"message":"VALUE_OF_MESSAGE"}
      var message=resp.message;
     document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML= ``${message}`; 
     });
   ```

   You can perform fetch request whenever you want to and any number of times.

2.)If you have to do something with elements in the page to update your message
variable, I recommend you to use JavaScript directly.

Comment: Thank you , but if i use this how should i return my render template?

Comment: you will render your template only once which has the variable 'message'.Then you update your variable through javascript every time you fetch data. (someElement.innerHTML='${message}').

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you can solve it by doing the following....
You need to create a loop.. it will look something like this..

Before your html code type in `{% for message in messages %}`
And after your html code type in `{% endfor %}`

Hopefully it works....

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I tried this before and it just loops through the message and displays its characters alone